# Magento 2 : Update Custom Column Value in Sales Order Grid Table

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-grid, column

I have added custom column in `sales_order_grid` table and values are showing in backend but how to update that column's value if customer has edited it from frontend order view?
Anyone please help!

installer code

```
$setup->getConnection()
    ->addColumn(
        $setup->getTable($ordergridTable),
        'custom_column',
        [
            'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
            'unsigned'  => true,
            'nullable'  => false,
            'default'   => '0',
            'comment' =>'Custom column'
        ]
    );

    $setup->getConnection()->addIndex(
    $setup->getTable($ordergridTable),
    $setup->getConnection()->getIndexName(
    $setup->getTable($ordergridTable),
    ['custom_column']
    ),
    ['custom_column']
    );
```

Below is code from my model where i am saving it in `sales_order` table:

```
public function setFav($order,$orderId,$favId)
{

    $order = $order->create();
    $order->load($orderId);
    if($favId==0){
       $order->setCustomColumn(1);
    }else{
       $order->setCustomColumn(0);
    }
    $order->save();
}
```

It is saving in `sales_order` table but need to save/update in `sales_order_grid` at same time.
Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me how you can add that column and also share code to save value into this field.

Comment: Please check updated post